# NodeJS: How to trigger the Pause/Play Media Key on Windows

Tags: node.js, simulation, media-player, keypress

I simply want to simulate/trigger the Pause/Play media key. Same thing as when you click on your wireless earbuds to pause/play music currently playing from any program/medium (such as YouTube).

I tried using robotjs, "Error: Invalid key code specified."

```js
robot.keyTap("mediaplaypause");
```

I tried using xdotool (https://github.com/ebranlard/xdotool-for-windows) and nothing happens:

```js
exec("xdotool key XF86AudioPlay", (error, stdout, stderr) => { ...
```

No errors though from xdotool.

Any ideas on what I can do to simulate this dang key/function?